# append text to the end of the file

Tags: android

I am using the below code segment to write text to the end o the file for each time it is called. But, it is erasing the old data and then writes the new data to the beginning of the file. How can I fix the below code so that it is append new data **always** end of the file ?

```
public boolean writeToFile(String directory, String filename, String data ){
    File out;
    OutputStreamWriter outStreamWriter = null;
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;

    out = new File(new File(directory), filename);

    if ( out.exists() == false ){
                out.createNewFile();
    }

    outStream = new FileOutputStream(out) ;
    outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream); 

    outStreamWriter.append(data);
    outStreamWriter.flush();
   }
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to set append `boolean` value to true in `FileOutputStream`:

```
outStream = new FileOutputStream(out, true);
outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream);
```

Comment: error : `the constructor OutputStreamWriter(FileOutputStream, boolean) is undefined`

Comment: look at me answer man, second parameter of `FileOutputStream` not `OutputStreamWriter`.